# Django ModelAdmin.get_urls() not registering custom urls

Tags: django, django-admin

I am trying to create custom views for my models in Django admin site. I created `ModelAdmin` for my model named `Document` like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app.models import Document


@admin.register(Document)
class DocumentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            path('my-view/', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.my_view))
        ]

        return urls + custom_urls

    def my_view(self, request):
        return HttpResponse('test')
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) (v2.1) I should be able to access `my_view` with `/admin/my_app/document/my-view` but when I try to visit this URL django redirects me to admin homepage with the following warning:

```
Document with ID "my-view" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?
```

So it looks like django cannot see my custom url. What am I missing? How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is just a matter of URL ordering; the generic admin change view is processed first and is capturing your request for "my-view" as a slug. You can change this by putting your URLs first, which is what is actually done in the example you link to:

```
return custom_urls + urls
```